# How do I prove that the interior of a tetrahedron is nonempty?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $C$ be a bounded convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Int(C)=\emptyset$ and $0\in C$. Then, how do I prove that $C$ is contained in some $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $m<n$?

Suppose not. Then, there exist $v_1,...,v_n\in C$ such that $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define $H:=\{\sum_{i=1}^nt_iv_i:t_i\in [0,1], \sum_{i=1}^n t_i\leq 1 \}$.

Let $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ be the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, there exists a linear homeomorphism $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $T(v_i)=e_i$.

Define $G:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\leq 1\}$. Since $T(H)=G$, it suffices to show that $G$ has an interior point. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G$ contains the set $G^\circ=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_i>0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i<1\}$ which can be written as the intersection of the $n+1$ sets

\begin{align}
T&=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\sum_{i=1}^n x_i<1\right\}\\
E_j&=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_j>0\right\}
\end{align}

where $j=1,\dots,n$. It is enough to show that the sets $T$ and $E_j$ are all open (**hint:** each of them can be written as the preimage of an open set under a continuous function).

Comment: Oh right.. foolish me. Thank you

Comment: Minor nit: we should also observe that $G^\circ$ is nonempty since it contains, say, $(1/(2n), \ldots, 1/(2n))$.